# Excel: No. of Weekdays in a given week

Tags: vba, excel

My Data

```
    A               B       C
1   Created Date    Week    No. of WorkDays
2   6/20/2018 11:36 06-w4   5
3   6/26/2018 12:56 06-w5   5
4   7/6/2018 23:01  07-w1   5
5   6/18/2018 18:11 06-w4   5
6   6/15/2018 12:01 06-w3   5
7   6/1/2018 13:31  06-w1   1
8   6/8/2018 12:17  06-w2   5
9   6/1/2018 13:32  06-w1   1
10  7/30/2018 13:32 07-w5   2
```

I have a week function that says whether an issue was created in Week 1 or 2 or so on. But for my calculation I need to consider workdays in that week, how do I do it. I'm calculating the no. of weekdays in that week manually now.

For example: June Week 1: No. of Weekdays is 1, because June 1 is Friday and June 2 is Saturday. Similarly for July Week 5 it is 2 days because July 29 is Sunday, July 30 & 31 are the weekdays.

My current formula for Week is

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1,"MM"),"-w",WEEKNUM(A1,1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),1),1)+1)
```

I'm trying out to use Workday function, but it does not provide my desired result.

Kindly help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date in the A column is always a weekday, you can use this:
If that date can also be a weekend day, it will take the working days of the previous week. If you want to take the workinf days of the next week, you have to fiddle around still a bit.

```
=MIN(5,IF(MONTH(A2-WEEKDAY(A2,3))<MONTH(A2),7-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),1),1),IF(MONTH(A2+5-WEEKDAY(A2,2))>MONTH(A2),WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,0),2),5)))
```

- First MIN: restrict to max 5 working days
- First IF(): check if monday before or on date in A2 is in previous month
- If so: take 7 minus weekday of first of month (sunday being 1)
- If not so: second IF: check if friday this week is in next month
- If so: take the weekday of the last of this month (monday being 1)
- If not so: week in the middle of month, return 5

This of course does not take into account public holidays, only weekends.

Comment: Haha! No, vba would actually look nice and understandable if I had written it. This not so. It’s Excel  Usually I refrain from using vba functions in Excel as much as possible, since it won’t work if your debugging in vba and evaluating excel at the same time, it gets annoying and it may become very slow.

Answer (score 0):

For an inclusive # or workdays (e.g. Friday is 1 workday) try,

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2, A2+5-WEEKDAY(A2,2), 1)
```

NETWORKDAYS.INTL allows for an optional holiday list if you want to create one.

Comment: This solution does not give the results that are given in the question at all.

Comment: You're calculating the number of days to the date in A2 to next friday. But the OP wants the number of working days in that week, in which A2 is, unrelated to on  which weekday A2 is.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote my own VBA Formula - Results are as below

```
    A               B       C               D
1   Created Date    Week    No. of WorkDays No. of Days - Formula
2   6/20/2018 11:36 06-w4   5               5
3   3/2/2018 12:56  03-w1   2               2
4   7/6/2018 23:01  07-w1   5               5
5   6/18/2018 18:11 06-w4   5               5
6   6/15/2018 12:01 06-w3   5               5
7   6/1/2018 13:31  06-w1   1               1
8   6/8/2018 12:17  06-w2   5               5
9   6/1/2018 13:32  06-w1   1               1
10  7/30/2018 13:32 07-w5   2               2
```

Formula

```
=CalculateWorkdaysInWeek(A2)
```

VBA Code

```
Function CalculateWorkdaysInWeek(WeekRange As Range) As Variant
    'Assume Week 2, 3 & 4 will always have 5 days
    Dim WeekNo As Double
    'Check if Week is 1 or 5
    WeekNo = (Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(WeekRange, 1) - _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(DateSerial(Year(WeekRange), Month(WeekRange), 1))) + 1

    Dim NoOfWeekDays As Integer
    If WeekNo = 1 Then
        FirstWeekDay = 7 - Weekday(DateSerial(Year(WeekRange), Month(WeekRange), 1), vbSunday)
        If FirstWeekDay > 5 Then
            FirstWeekDay = 5
        End If
        NoOfWeekDays = FirstWeekDay
    ElseIf WeekNo = 5 Then
        'Check the last day of the month as Monday as Start
        LastWeekDay = Weekday(DateSerial(Year(WeekRange), Month(WeekRange) + 1, 0), vbMonday)
        If LastWeekDay > 5 Then
            LastWeekDay = 5
        End If
        NoOfWeekDays = LastWeekDay
    Else ' Week 2,3 & 4 Return 5
        NoOfWeekDays = 5
    End If

    CalculateWorkdaysInWeek = NoOfWeekDays
End Function
```